# How to make PHP version 8 support constructor with same name as class?

Tags: php, php-8

I have a legacy project being migrated to PHP version 8, but the new PHP version doesn't support class constructor named based on the class name, which worked in old versions.

I want classes like this to continue working:

```
class Person {
    
    private $fname;
    private $lname;
    
    // Constructor same class name here
    public function Person($fname, $lname) {
        $this->fname = $fname;
        $this->lname = $lname;
    }
    
    // public method to show name
    public function showName() {
        echo "My name is: " . $this->fname . " " . $this->lname . "<br/>"; 
    }
}

// creating class object
$john = new Person("John", "Wick");
$john->showName();
```

Comment: You need to specify your current version of PHP, and don't expect people to translate your code, being more generic here would be better for the community considering that other people may face the same issue but with a different class

Comment: @DouglasFerreira from PHP 5.3 to PHP 8, I tried many research no solution beside refactor as I already marked as an answered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a case of a setting that you can turn back on, I'm afraid, the functionality was permanently removed from PHP. It might be possible to write some kind of extension which emulated the old behaviour, but it's going to be a lot more work in the long run than doing a one-off fix to all your existing files.

Your best bet is probably to use a tool such as [Rector](https://getrector.org/) which can automate the upgrade process. In this case, using the [Php4ConstructorRector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/blob/main/docs/rector_rules_overview.md#php4constructorrector) rule looks like it should do it all for you.

Comment: Thank you much with your solution "Php4ConstructorRector" I am done it works and it does more then Constructor it improve more quality code and suggesting some last functions

Answer (score 3):

Change `Person` to `__construct`

```
public function __construct($fname, $lname) {
    $this->fname = $fname;
    $this->lname = $lname;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/Ke39i

Comment: But will need to change hundreds existing files that why I looking for option that can enable support constructor the same class name.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good practice so far and deprecated in PHP. You will be in trouble if you are using the constructor name as like method name in future. Better constructor use as`__construcotr`.

```
class Person {

    private $fname;
    private $lname;

    // Constructor same class name here
    public function __construct($fname, $lname) {
        $this->fname = $fname;
        $this->lname = $lname;
    }

    // public method to show name
    public function showName() {
        echo "My name is: " . $this->fname . " " . $this->lname . "<br/>";
    }
}

// creating class object
$john = new Person("John", "Wick");
$john->showName();
```